# Mongoose schemas with unknown keys and nested documents as values

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a document out of Mongo that looks something like this:

```
{
    teacher: { name: 'Fred' },
    principal: { name: 'Bob' },
    student: { name: 'Sally' }
}
```

In my case, the properties of "teacher", "principal" and "student" are totally arbitrary and can be any old string.  It's unknown before this particular document is loaded what they will be.  However, I know that every value of every property at this document level will be of the same type and can therefore validate it.

I would like to make each of these values a [sub-document within Mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html) (a "Person") to leverage Mongoose's validation; however, I cannot find a way to tell mongoose to treat all values as the same schema type regardless of key.

By the way, I can't convert this into an array where each Person has "role" type or anything like that.  I unfortunately don't control the data structure, I just get to consume it!

Any ideas appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If you recieve this as a dict, you could implement a converter method that attempts to parse each key value as a Person, something like this:

```
var utils = require('restberry-utils');

var PersonSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {type: String},
    ...
});
var Person = mongoose.model('Person', PersonSchema);

var parsePersons = function(persons, next) {
    var parsedPersons = {};
    var names = Object.keys(persons);
    utils.forEachAndDone(names, function(name, iter) {
        var personData = persons[name];
        Person.findOne(personData, function(err, person) {
            if (err) ...
            if (!person) {
                person = new Person(personData);
            }
            parsedPersons[name] = person;
            person.save(iter);
        })
    }, function() {
        next(parsedPersons);
    })
};

var persons = ...  // your dict
parsePersons(persons, function(parsedPersons) {
    ...
});
```

Does this solve your problem?

Comment: @AdamTerlson I know what you mean. The ideal solution would be to have it be parsed automatically but you could put this in some some module and have it be called along ever person get, imitating some automation. I don't know, sky's the limit :P what du you thing?